# C# object looks like dynamic type

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic

Have been playing around with the 4.0 DLR and was comparing dynamic to object and came across this:

Code:

```
object x = 10;
            Console.WriteLine("x = {0} and is a {1}.\n", x, x.GetType());
            x = (int)x + 3;
            Console.WriteLine("x = {0} and is a {1}.\n", x, x.GetType());
            x = x + "a";
            Console.WriteLine("x = {0} and is a {1}.\n", x, x.GetType());
```

Result:

> x = 10 and is a System.Int32.
>
> x = 13 and is a System.Int32.
>
> x = 13a and is a System.String.

To me, it looks like object tries to fit the object to a type at runtime (dynamic). However if I don't cast x to an int on the 3rd line, it gives me a compiler area which seems correct for static typing.  But then it allows me to add an "a" to x and now it recognizes it as a string.

What am I missing?

Comment: I wonder if it's because the String is actually an Object, but the 3 is a base type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are missing the fact that the `+` operator, when applied to strings, does an automatic conversion (by calling the `.ToString()` method on the operand that is not an instance of the `String` type).

Answer (score 4):

From the [C# Language Specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228593.aspx):

> **7.8.4 Addition operator**
>
> When one or both operands are of type string, the predefined addition operators concatenate the string representation of the operands.
>
> - String concatenation:
>
>   ```
>   string operator +(string x, string y);
>   string operator +(string x, object y);
>   string operator +(object x, string y);
>   ```
>
>   These overloads of the binary + operator perform string concatenation. If an operand of string concatenation is `null`, an empty string is substituted. Otherwise, any non-string argument is converted to its string representation by invoking the virtual `ToString` method inherited from type object. If `ToString` returns `null`, an empty string is substituted.

Answer (score 2):

Bear in mind that there's a distinction between the type of the *variable* (which is `object`) and the type of the object it references.

The last conversion is allowed because the `System.String` type defines an operator that accepts an `object` as one of the values and performs an automatic `ToString()` on it.

There's no funny business with the runtime or dynamic operations.

Answer (score 1):

> To me, it looks like object tries to fit the object to a type at runtime (dynamic).

Not really: it simply exercises .NET's `object`'s ability to store objects of any type.

In order to be `dynamic`, a variable should allow you to call anything without a cast, for example

```
dynamic x = "hello";
dynamic y = x.Substring(0, 2); // The compiler does not complain
```

If you try to pull off the above trick with a "plain" `object`, you would get an angry message from the compiler. The use of `dynamic`, however, postpones complaining until runtime, at which point it may happen, or may not happen at all.

> But then it allows me to add an "a" to x and now it recognizes it as a string.

That's "a piece of magic" the compiler does: it knows that `object` has a `ToString`, and inserts the call for you automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Since all types in C# derived from [object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.aspx) types, it can store *any types*.

```
object x = 10;
x = x + "a";
```

That what the compilers do actually. Since `object` has `.ToString()`, when you use `+`, compiler call it automaticly.

Even when we look at *IL* code of this;

```
  .locals init ([0] object x)
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  ldc.i4.s   10
  IL_0003:  box        [mscorlib]System.Int32
  IL_0008:  stloc.0
  IL_0009:  ldloc.0
  IL_000a:  ldstr      "a"
  IL_000f:  call       string [mscorlib]System.String::Concat(object,
                                                              object)
```

Return value of this `String.Concat` method is `string` representations of the values.

From **[C# 5.0 Specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228593.aspx)**:

> - String concatenation:
>
>   ```
>   string operator +(string x, string y);
>   string operator +(string x, object y);
>   string operator +(object x, string y);
>   ```
>
>   These overloads of the binary + operator perform string concatenation. If an operand of string concatenation is `null`, an empty string is substituted. Otherwise, any non-string argument is converted to its string representation by invoking the virtual `ToString` method inherited from type object. If `ToString` returns `null`, an empty string is substituted.

Comment: What's interesting is why `x + "a"` generates a call to `Concat` in IL.  That it does so is obvious enough from the output.  The reasoning is explained in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14967141/1159478)

Comment: @Servy The truth is, when I see first time calling `Concat` in IL, I was suprised also. I just decompiled `String.Concat(obj, obj)` and here the result; `public static string Concat(object arg0, object arg1)
    {
      if (arg0 == null)
        arg0 = (object) string.Empty;
      if (arg1 == null)
        arg1 = (object) string.Empty;
      return arg0.ToString() + arg1.ToString();
    }` I think this process use `.ToString()` method using `String.Concat(obj, obj)` method.

Answer (score 0):

Everything in C# inherits from `object`. `int`, `string`, `char`, etc all do.

When you do this:

```
object x = 10;
```

You're creating a variable, `x`, and then initializing it to the integer value 10. The value is an `int`, it's just being `boxed` into an object.

When you cast `x` as an `int` you're `unboxing` it to it's actual type.

Review this guide for [Boxing and Unboxing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

all data types on c# inherited from "object" so the basic behaviour on any operation depends on the operator & the other object